# Elasticsearch: multiple sorts for nested fields

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nested

have a situation where treatment has a price and hospital may or may not want to display it.
so there is a price field PLUS a `lp_low_priority` field.
value of `lp_low_priority` is 1(true) when price is not set(price is_null).

hospital doc is saved with its nested treatments.
when user searches for treatment he get list of hospitals with minimum price of the treatment.
now the sort works fine.
BUT i want the hospital with that treatment with the `lp_low_priority = 1` to come at last.
Code to search is like

```
{
      "sort": [
        {
          "treatments.lowest_price": {
            "nested_filter": {
              "term": {
                "treatments.treatment_slug": "heart-surgery"
              }
            },
            "mode": "avg",
            "order": "asc"
          }
        },
        {
          "treatments.lp_low_priority": {
            "order": "asc",
            "nested_filter": {
              "term": {
                "treatments.treatment_slug": "heart-surgery"
              }
            },
            "mode": "max"
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "treatments.treatment_slug": "heart-surgery"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "treatments.status": "active"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "treatments.treatment_status": "active"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "hospital_status": "active"
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "location.country": [
                  "India"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

the result is way too weird.
if I only use

```
{
          "sort": [
            {
              "treatments.lowest_price": {
                "nested_filter": {
                  "term": {
                    "treatments.treatment_slug": "heart-surgery"
                  }
                },
                "mode": "avg",
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
```

The sorting is in order but then you see the `lp_low_priority` come first in order, which is OK(but not the requirement).
Can i even use more than one sorts for nested fields.